# What levels-up Psi-abilities?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

It is apparent that kills gives you experience that gain you promotion for your normal abilities. How does it work for Psi-abilities? What grants experience/promotion points for Psi-ability promotions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Psi XP is granted for the following activities:

- Resist Psi Attack - 10
- Successful Mindfray - 20
- Successful Mind Inspiration - 30
- Assist Mind Inspiration - 30
- Successful Psi Panic - 30

You need 50 psi xp to go from Psionic to Specialist, and 120 xp to go from Specialist to Operative.

Comment: What do successful and assist mind inspirations mean? I never saw an inspiration fail.

Comment: Not sure, but I would assume when another soldier under psi inspiration uses a psi ability successfully.